# Creating JournalEntry with VAT on QuickBooks Online

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

I would like to create a journal entry that has VAT for some of the lines. I use UK sandbox for development.
At first I created a journal entry containing two lines:

```
<JournalEntry xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3">
    <TxnDate>2017-01-26</TxnDate>
    <Line>
        <Amount>20.0</Amount>
        <DetailType>JournalEntryLineDetail</DetailType>
        <JournalEntryLineDetail>
            <PostingType>Credit</PostingType>
            <AccountRef name="Commission Income">94</AccountRef>
            <TaxCodeRef name="Lithuania VAT">41</TaxCodeRef>
            <TaxApplicableOn>Sales</TaxApplicableOn>
            <TaxAmount>10</TaxAmount>
        </JournalEntryLineDetail>
    </Line>
    <Line>
        <Description>TEST: PLACEHOLDER FOR BALANCING</Description>
        <Amount>20</Amount>
        <DetailType>JournalEntryLineDetail</DetailType>
        <JournalEntryLineDetail>
            <PostingType>Debit</PostingType>
            <AccountRef name="Transaction Cost">142</AccountRef>
        </JournalEntryLineDetail>
    </Line>
</JournalEntry>
```

First line containing actual data, second line is for testing purpose (balancing debit and credit). AccountRefs and TaxCodeRef are valid, they were fetched from QB just before creating journal entry. When I add the entry I get the following error:

> ERROR CODE:6000, ERROR MESSAGE:A business validation error has
>   occurred while processing your request, ERROR DETAIL:Business
>   Validation Error: We're sorry, QuickBooks encountered an error while
>   calculating tax. Try reselecting the tax rate or reentering the
>   product/service item and saving the form again. https://support.qbo.intuit.com/support/help-article.cfm?faq_id=5558&locale=en_GB'
>   target="_blank" title="Help">Please click here for more
>   information, MORE ERROR DETAIL:

The provided link doesn't work. I'm not able to figure out what should I change on JournalEntry to fullfill business validation.

Thanks,

Hubi